# Get runtime property for the same element

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-webdriver

When we enter text in google search textbox it auto-suggest the options, the objects changes.

Now I want to click the *Search* button which was earlier *Google Search*.

I have created the *Google Search* button with `name` property and `btnK` is the value.

Now as the property changes to `btnG`, so how I can retrieve the properties and then use this property value to identify the object.

This sounds like dead-end because object changes and so we cannot retrieve it's value. I believe we can use dynamic property here. But I am stuck here! I am using *Selenium webdriver with Java*.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Given that in this specific case the name property is dynamic, I would recommend trying an alternative selector that is static instead. For example, using google.com, we can select the button using the code below.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Google Search']"))
```

If you do wish to stick with checking a dynamic value, you can check for part of the name using contains in the css selector.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name*='btn']"))
```

This should pull in both the google search button and I'm feeling lucky button. I recommend the approach further above that uses value in the selector because it is more specific.